# Seeking 9-bit serial port card for Windows PC

Tags: windows, serial-port

[Update] This question was correctly closed several years ago. However, nowadays, it could be asked on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - I just wanted to make others aware of this very helpful site.

---

I need to connect to serial port on a system bus which uses 9 data bits.

Is there an off the shelf card which will handle that? Obviously it would need to come with driver software to return 9 (actually 16, with 7 unused) bits for each `character` sent on the serial bus.

Comment: Which serial adapters have you tried already?  Can you provide some context as to why you need this? Specific abilities your are expecting (beyond 'return 9-bits')

Comment: as far as I know serial means bits are sent one after another, are you maybe looking for a parallel solution? (I have to add that I am just getting into this topic) 

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_communication

Comment: How critical is the application?  8 bit buses often have a 9th bit for parity which you could usurp as an extra data bit.  You'll want to provide a lot more detail about what you are up to...

Comment: +1 "Which serial adapters have you tried already?" None "Can you provide some context as to why you need this?" No need (and commercal confidential)- just 9 data bits is all. "Specific abilities your are expecting (beyond 'return 9-bits')" None - just 9 data bits inplace of the more common 8.

Comment: Walter, Nope, not parallel. @Paul +1 There _are_ kudlges which use the parity bit as a 9th data bit, but they tricky to implement (I have researched). I will not implement. I might - *in extremis* - purchase usch a solution, but *strongly* prefer a full 9 bits data plus start/stop/parity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are USARTs that can send & receive 9 bits of data (with or without parity) per character.  But I have only seen them as an integrated device that is part of a microcontroller or System-on-a Chip (SoC).  I've seen 9-bit capable USARTs on Atmel ARM and AVR SoCs. The typical 8250 or 16550 type of UART (that are considered PC-compatible devices) are not capable of 9-bit characters, and are limited to 8 bits per character.

However there are various kludges to use 8 data bits plus the parity bit to simulate a 9-bit character.

[Use The PC's UART With 9-Bit Protocols](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/embedded-revolution/article/21763399/use-the-pcs-uart-with-9bit-protocols)

[Can I Do 9-bit Serial Communication Instead of 7 or 8 bits?](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019MV3SAM)

One scheme for transmission is to reconfigure the UART parity (to ODD or EVEN) before each byte transmission, according to the 9th data bit and the parity of the lower 8 bits.  Receiving a 9-bit character is a bit trickier, as each character's 9th bit has to be derived from the parity of the received 8 bits plus whether or not there was a *parity error* for that byte.  This scheme should be done at the device driver level, and may significantly reduce data throughput.

ADDENDUM

> I am looking for a natie 9-bit card + driver for Windows.

Then this is technically a shopping question, which is not allowed on SU.

However I did find exactly what you are asking for (and it's not cheap):

[Sealevel 7205e : Low Profile PCI Express RS-232, RS-422, RS-485 Serial Interface](https://www.sealevel.com/product/7205e-low-profile-pci-express-2-port-rs-232-rs-422-rs-485-serial-interface/)

> The 7205e low-profile PCI Express serial interface provides two serial ports configurable for **RS-232**, RS-422 or RS-485. Each serial port utilizes a 16C950 UART with 128-byte Tx/Rx FIFOs that enables data rates to 921.6K bps for reliable high-speed communications in data intensive applications. **This high-performance UART includes 9-bit framing support** and is fully software compatible with legacy 16550 applications. In addition, the 14.7456 oscillator and UART's flexible clock prescalar supports the widest range of standard and non-standard baud rates.

Comment: +1  I am using an Atmel UC3 wth native 9 bit support & need to handle the communication on a PC. So, I am looking for a natie 9-bit card + driver for Windows.  Walter, Nope, not parallel. @Paul +1 There are kudlges which use the parity bit as a 9th data bit, but they tricky to implement (I have researched). I will not implement. I might - in extremis - purchase usch a solution, but strongly prefer a full 9 bits data plus start/stop/parity. – Mawg just now edit

Comment: @Mawg - added PCIe board solution to answer.

Comment: +1 Wow, you weren't joking "not cheap"  $260!!   I will keep googling, I think :-)

Comment: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007531%20600022027&IsNodeId=1    SYBA PCI-Express 4 Port Serial Card Model SY-PEX-4S

    Type: PCI Express to Serial Port Card
    External Ports: 4 x Serial Ports
Serial Modem Control Supports Hardware, Software flow control 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9-bit Serial format Support Even, Odd, None, Space & Mark parity supported Custom BAUD Rates supported with external clock or by programming internal PLL On Chip 256 Byte depth FIFOs in

Comment: @Mawg - Use those low-cost adapters with caution.  Apparently they use the MCS9901CV UART.  A manufactuer's datasheet for the actual chip does not mention 9-bit capability, only the standard 5, 6, 7 & 8-bit data lengths.  http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=120;74;110&PLine=74  A **press release** by MOSCHIP claims 9-bit data capability, but I can't find a **datasheet** that actually supports that marketing claim.  9-bit data length does not seem to be a capability of any of the 16C450 / 550 / Extended 550 / 650 UARTs.

Comment: The 16950 (or 16C950) UART is the chip you want for 9-bit data.  http://www.dcd.pl/workspace/documentation/gen/d16950_ds.pdf